# Laravel 5.6: Skip validation step if field exists and isn't changed. If field IS changed it is Required - but not unique

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-validation

I have situation where an admin edits an employee form: The first name, last name, and SSN are required on ADDING an employee. No problems there. Where I have an issue is when EDITING the form. I have no problem validating the SSN as it is a unique field.

```
'ssn_edit' => 'required|unique:employees,ssn,' . $id
```

But what I DO have an issue with is the non-unique fields. I don't know how to set the validation to skip by ID when the field is NOT unique.  Here is the entire rules section of the FormRequest:

```
public function rules()
{
    $id = $this->input('employee_id');
    return [
        'first_name' => 'required',
        'last_name' => 'required',
        'ssn_edit' => 'required|unique:employees,ssn,' . $id
    ];
}
```

Obviously - this throws the validation error on first_name and last_name regardless if the field is populated or not.
Any help some of you Laravel gurus can throw my way would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: When you edit the employee then first_name and last_name fields won't be there?

Comment: Laravel sees it that way if the values were not changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is so many tricks you can do to solve the problem. But I only got two ways..

The first is: Prevent to send your ssn_edit value when you want to edit the employee

example:

```
<input type="text" value="{{ isset($employee) ? $employee->ssn_edit : old('ssn_edit') }}" @isset($employee) disabled @endisset name="ssn_edit">

public function rules()
{
    $id = $this->input('employee_id');
    return [
        'first_name' => 'required',
        'last_name' => 'required',
        'ssn_edit' => 'required|sometimes|unique:employees,ssn,' . $id
    ];
}
```

The second is: Check your method before validate the employee.. is it `POST` or `PUT`, if it's `PUT` don't add the unique rule in your validation.

Conclusion: The validation will work every time you call the validation, no matter if you edit or add new employee. #CMIIW

Answer (score 0):

You mustn't have error with validating non-unique fields, probably you have wrong edit form, set `value` attribute to input like

```
<input type="text" value="{{ $employee->first_name }}" name="first_name">
```